# Adding Swagger API Documentation to Maven Site

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, code-documentation, maven-site-plugin, api-doc

I have a Spring Boot project and I'm using swagger to test and document the API. The project also contains a bunch of classes that are used as libraries and I'm using scala docs to document those. Is there a way to unify API docs (from swagger) and Scala Docs as I'm hosting the docs using maven site plugin.